# Parsing JSON in photoshop

Tags: json, photoshop-script

I've recently found out that you can parse JSON files in photoshop using [jamJSON](http://www.tonton-pixel.com/blog/)

This is good news, but I've got a couple of stumbling blocks:
For example, this is my JSON file

```
{
"YEAR" : {
  "longname" : "New Year"
 }
}
```

I can access it with

```
var jsObj = jamJSON.parse (jsonText, true);
alert (jsObj["YEAR"]["longname"]) // New Year
```

But since each file is going to be different and "YEAR" may be "FRUIT" or "GOLD" in another file. How do I access the data without knowing the first part of the object?

Comment: `jsObj[0]["longname"]`

Comment: Although the answers below are correct I was getting confused between object and arrays and was finally able to access the data using '    var jsObj = jamJSON.parse (jsonText, true);

  for (var key in jsObj) 
  {
    var obj = jsObj[key];
    alert (obj["longname"]);
  }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answers are above are correct, I was getting confused between object and arrays (Easily done. I'm an artist, me)  and was finally able to access the data using

```
 var jsObj = jamJSON.parse (jsonText, true);

  for (var key in jsObj) 
 {
   var obj = jsObj[key];
   alert (obj["longname"]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON file will always have a single entry with this format, you can indicate the index-position of the entry rather than the name. For example:

```
alert (jsObj["YEAR"]["longname"]) // New Year
```

is equivalent to:

```
alert (jsObj[0]["longname"]) // New Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Best, use JSONPath JS, easy to use and fast as well. You can access the value without knowing the key name by this:

```
alert(jsonPath(jsObj, "$..longname"))
```